# Client side caching in ArcGIS JSAPI maps

Tags: arcgis-10.3, arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is it possible to cache a map layer or feature layer on client side (the browser) using ArcGIS JSAPI, if so, can someone provide a link to documentation and/or samples?

If not, what other client technologies (e.g. Flex, .Net, SilverLight) support caching in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the ArcGIS JSAPI itself does not provide any tools for caching map layers or features layer on the client side.

However, there are generic html/javascript tools for storing data that could be used to store it and then read in to populate e.g. a feature layer. For example IndexedDB which is used in the no longer maintained https://github.com/Esri/offline-editor-js.

If you're not limiting yourself to the browser, then the ArcGIS Runtime SDKs can provide great offline solutions, see for example https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/guide/create-an-offline-map.htm.